# Nothing is showing up in my jsp from my database. Please anyone

Tags: java, html, jsp, oracle11g

please anyone help me with this problem. I am running eclipse. The ResultSet is generating a string pointing to database bu when it gets into table data. It isn't printing anything. I am not able to fetch data from Database in short.
The jsp code is:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

        <%
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","SYSTEM","mihir");
      %>

<h2 align="center"><font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">

    <tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
        <td><b>id</b></td>
        <td><b>user_id</b></td>
        <td><b>Password</b></td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Email</b></td>
    </tr>
   <%
    String sear ="SELECT * FROM record";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( sear );
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
    %>
        <tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

            <td><%=rs.getString("ID") %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("USER_ID") %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("PASSWORD") %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("NAME") %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString("EMAIL") %></td>

        </tr>

    <%      
        }
%>
</table>
```

and the database I created is:

```
CREATE TABLE record (
  2            id varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  3            user_id varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  4            password varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  5            name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  6            email varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  7            PRIMARY KEY (id)
  8          );
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Could you post your error message? Please also don't code like this for a serious implementation.

Comment: Situations like this are a very good reason not to use Java code embedded in JSPs (scriptlets) but to use distinct controllers for that and only use HTML templates for presentation.

Comment: There are not any error messages. Just the data is not showing. I have did some changes. Pls see. @YohannesGebremariam

Comment: But I believe there is still a way to do this. I intend on learning that @chrylis

Comment: Have you checked server logs? Do you see empty HTML table in your JSP or just blank page?

Comment: I see empty HTML table. I think you are close to solution. @Ivan

Comment: Empty HTML table and no exceptions means that there is no data in database. Have you executed your query separately?

Comment: Yes in sql query select * from works in that table. @Ivan

Comment: @MihirKumar, are you sure? I've just used your code but to connect to my database and it shows data from my table. So code works.

Comment: It's working? Do you used even the same database schemas? @Ivan

Comment: Did you made any changes other than your localhost and username and password? @Ivan

Comment: Thank you very much @Ivan . The problem is solved. It was there because the domain for data in my database where too large for a getString() parameter. You helped a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using MySQL driver to connect to Oracle database. Try with correct driver.

```
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
```

Comment: Pls elaborate. What can I use here?